# Can not update mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I'm building a login system(PHP). I'm trying to make a password recovery script based on random codes and an expiration date for them. When I try to add the generated random code to the db, nothing happens. 
Here is my code:

forgotpass.php

```
function procForgotPass(){
  global $database, $session, $mailer, $form;

  $subuser = $_POST['user'];

     //$expdate=Date('y:m:d', strtotime("+1 day"));
    $password_token= urlencode($this->nonce());
    $database->addkey($subuser, $password_token, "2012-12-19 13:37:14");
} //THE CODE IS LONGER, JUST MAKING IT SIMPLE

function nonce($size=32){//256 bit == 32byte. 
$ret="";
for($x=0;$x<$size;$x++){
    $ret.=chr(mt_rand(0,255));
}
return base64_encode($ret); }
```

database.php

```
function addkey($username, $key, $date){
  $w = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_CODES." (username, Key, expDate) VALUES ('$username', '$key', '$date')";
  return mysql_query($w, $this->connection); }
```

I'm not going to post the connection() because it's working(I can register users and etc).
What can it be?

I can execute a code just like that to create users, but this one is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to type:

```
`key`
```

not

```
key
```

Word `key` is reserved in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for edit @Shredder I'm new and don't know how write gravis :P